# How to print the <i> tag directly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy the  tag directly with some custom item using clipboard API. everything is working fine. I mean when I am trying to copy a normal text it copied but when I am trying to copy the following cs variable.

```
  for (index in result) {
  var icon_name = result[index].icon_name;
  var icon_code = result[index].icon_code;
  var icon_code_css = result[index].icon_code_css;
  var cs = '<i class="'+icon_code+'"></i>';
  var tr = '<tr class="v-middle">';
  tr += '<td><span><i class="' + icon_code + ' _icons"></i></span></td>';
  tr += '<td class="flex text-color">' + icon_name + '</td>';
  tr += '<td class="text-color"><span>'+icon_code+'</span><input type="text" id="'+icon_code_css+'" aria-hidden="true" class="offscreen form-control" value="'+icon_code+'"></td>';
  tr += '<td class="text-color"><span>'+icon_code_css+'</span><input type="text" id="'+icon_code_css+'_script" aria-hidden="true" class="offscreen form-control" value="'+cs+'"></td>';
  tr += '<td><span class="text-color">Material Design</span></td>';
  tr += '<td><span id="'+icon_code_css+'_1" class="badge bg-primary-lt" onclick="clip(this.id)" data-clipboard-target="#'+icon_code_css+'">Copy</span> <span id="'+icon_code_css+'_2" class="badge bg-primary-lt" onclick="clip(this.id)" data-clipboard-target="#'+icon_code_css+'_script">Copy script</span></td>';
  tr += "</tr>";
  $('#icontable tbody').append(tr);

}
```

its copy only `<i class=` this. can anyone help me how can I achieve?

Comment: The clipboard just contains the text, it doesn't contain the markup around it.

Comment: is it possible to achieve?

Comment: try ` var cs = ``<i class="${icon_code}"></i>`` `

Comment: @KunalMukherjee not working!

Comment: copy what and how? really unclear how you are copying it or adding it to the page.

Comment: It's 2019: don't use string concatenation, use template literals as Kunal suggests: ```var cs = `<i class="${result[index].icon_code"}></i>`;``` (note the use of backticks as enclosing syntax, not single/double quote symbols, and `${...}` for templating in values directly from JS context)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee if you want to use backticks _inside_ inline code, you'll need to use three backticks as enclosing syntax, not one.

Comment: @epascarello everything is working with the normal text like(dfjhfjdff) . but when i am trying to copy cs variable its not copying the full varaible...

Comment: Note that the syntax used to substitute the variable is irrelevant to the actual problem, it's just a style issue.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's what I was trying to do

Comment: @epascarello They said they're using a clipboard API, so they presumably mean they're doing something that copies the text of the element to the clipboard. And in this case, they want the clipboard to contain the italics.

Comment: Add the code for copying also, are you using `document.execCommand('copy')`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee if change the var cs = 'hello'; working perfect...

Comment: can anyone help

Comment: Post more code, more than 2 lines

Comment: If you `console.log(cs)` what is the result?

Comment: updated the code....

Comment: Change `var cs = '<i class="'+icon_code+'"></i>';` to `var cs = '<i class=\''+icon_code+'\'></i>';`

Comment: @Dimitar Awesome... Great... I am getting this result - <i class='mdi mdi-content-save-move-outline'></i> Now i want class to be enclosed in double quote("").

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var cs = '<i class="'+icon_code+'"></i>';
```

to

```
var cs = '<i class=&quot;'+icon_code+'&quot;></i>';
```

Here's an example input with double quotes:

```html
<input value="<i class=&quot;mdi mdi-content-save-move-outline&quot;></i>" style="width: 300px">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"<input ...... value="'+cs+'" />"
```

This yields:

```
<input ...... value="<i class="code"></i>" />
```

See how messed up that is? Try escaping the code appropriately.